# Is it possible for each of my iDevices to have its own iCloud backup?

Tags: ios, icloud, backup

But I would still like for all the devices to share a single iTunes account, so that

1. I only buy an app once
2. I want to be able to log into Find my iPhone with my main iTunes account and still see all my other devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One iCloud account is the primary account and only that account can use Find My Phone and Backup services, so to have one account with multiple devices implies that that same account also gets the iCloud backups.

However, iCloud doesn't co-mingle a backup from one iPhone 5 and another iPhone 5 (although you may want to choose different names for each to avoid confusion when restoring if you happen to have two of the same device).

Unless you are OK switching up accounts manually to push a backup to an alternate account and then switch right back, there currently isn't a way to do this with stock / unjailbroken iOS.

Comment: Perhaps someone will know of a jailbreak to mod this, but I'm not the best person for that info

Comment: You can also backup multiple iOS devices onto the same iCloud account. If you end up needing more than 5GB of space for the backup, simply purchase additional storage space. You can do this by going to Settings > iCloud > Storage & Backup > Change Storage Plan.